# C# Converting 32 Byte[] Key into 32 Characters any Encryption/Decryption Site would accept

Tags: c#, encryption

The following AES method generates a 32Bit[] Array, Every Value has its own 1-3 Characters, But what I require is a exact 32Bit Array

How is this Achieved?

```cs
    public byte[] keyStr;
    public string stringedKey;
    

Aes aes = Aes.Create();
aes.KeySize = 256;
aes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
aes.GenerateKey();
          
byte[] keyGenerated = aes.Key;
keyStr = keyGenerated;
stringedKey = BitConverter.ToString(keyStr);
```

Comment: What site would that be? Maybe they expect a hexadecimal key (2 characters per byte) for AES-128? `ToString` doesn't **just** generate hexadecimals, it infixes them with `-` characters.

Comment: https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/aes-encryption-decryption @MaartenBodewes As an example Im not sure im rather new to encryption in total so this is all a bit confusing for me, I did try to remove the - Characters are still above 32

Comment: Well, let me give you a very strong hint then: don't trust shit sites like that, they just lure you in to get hits. Here the key they expect is text, while a key should be fully randomized binary. Buy a book, follow a course and curse these online encryption BS sites after you did. There are a few decent ones though, I personally like [this one](https://cryptii.com/). The binary data of the key must be entered using hexadecimals.

Comment: Ah I appreciate that insight I Will do so I have been enjoying this far more then I thought I would Thanks again

Comment: I'm glad you do. If you get stuck just ask again. If you have questions about the cryptography itself, there's [crypto.se] as well - but don't forget to look for dupes and read a bit of help before you ask.